# How can I tell which iOS versions my XCode will deploy to?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I currently have XCode version 8.2.1.

On my iPhone, I currently have iOS 10.3.2.

My version of XCode will not deploy to anything over iOS 10.2.

On my iPhone, I am being offered an upgrade to iOS 11.0.3.

According to this wiki here, XCode version 9 will deploy to iOS 11.0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#9.x_series. But I can't tell whether this includes all the sub-versions, eg 11.0.3.

So my question is, if I get XCode version 9 and upgrade my phone to iOS 11.0.3, will I be able to deploy to my phone from XCode? How do I tell exactly which versions of iOS are supported by each version of XCode? And going forward, how can I ensure that my iPhone and iPad always have versions of iOS which I am able to deploy to from XCode?

Comment: You can _see_ in Xcode what your project's deployment target is. What problem are you actually having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I get XCode version 9 and upgrade my phone to iOS 11.0.3, will I be able to deploy to my phone from XCode?

**Yes.** Xcode 9 and iOS 11 are both the latest (as of Oct. 2017) versions available. If you want to support iOS 11, you need Xcode 9.

> How do I tell exactly which versions of iOS are supported by each version of XCode?

Check the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html). For example, the **Xcode 9 Compatibility** section says:

*Xcode 9 includes SDKs for iOS 11, watchOS 4, macOS 10.13, and tvOS 11*

> And going forward, how can I ensure that my iPhone and iPad always have versions of iOS which I am able to deploy to from XCode?

Staying current with the latest iOS and Xcode versions is one way to do that. You don't even need the latest iOS version on your phone -- just any version that's later than the minimum version supported by whatever Xcode you're using. Looking at the list of available deployment targets, I can see that Xcode 9 deploys to iOS versions back to iOS 9.1.

Mostly, just be aware that updating iOS on your phone may require you to also update Xcode.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. One more question: if a version of XCode supports "iOS 11", does that mean that it will always support sub-versions (eg 11.0.3), even those that haven't been released yet (eg 11.0.4)?

Comment: @ClareSudbery I guess it depends on what you mean by "support." The app you built with Xcode 9.0 will probably run fine on iOS 11.0.x, but Xcode 9.0 probably won't be able to let you run iOS 11.0.x on a simulator, for example, and Xcode 9.0 might or might not be able to deploy an app to a device running iOS 11.0.x.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you will be able to deploy to your phone.

While you need Xcode 9 and not 8 to program against iOS11, this question has more to do with the Base SDK and Deployment Target settings in your project.

The Base SDK is the SDK version you are compiling against. In Xcode 9, this could be iOS11, for example. The Deployment Target setting represents the lowest supported iOS version the app will run on. This might be iOS10, per your example, but it could be anything else.

To use the newest iOS11 features, you'd have to have a minimum Base SDK of iOS11. To support older platforms, you must make sure the Deployment Target is set to the oldest version you'd support. In code, you need to check the version of the platform when deciding to use a newer-than-Deployment-Target feature.

Comment: Right. And really to hammer the point: any version of Xcode can deploy to **any version of iOS that predates it** (and many that postdate it, after symbol collection). It's just up to you to declare which versions of iOS your code supports.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you - sadly I can't mark both answers with a tick, so I chose the other because it answered my basic questions, but this is also useful because of the details about deployment targets.